# django rest framework add user and create data in db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

every one,I now using django rest framework(3.4) on my project(django 1.8+),I can create new user but I can not use new user to create data in db(I can do it in forms ok), however,I can create data in db by admin. I have to make the new user to create data in db,how can I do that?thanks for any one who reply.

> models.py

```
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "這 model number 已經被註冊了 ."
        }
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    twtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hktime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jptime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()

class ProductsTblSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsTbl
        fields = ('model_number',
        'created',
        'name',
        'release',
        'twtime',
        'hktime',
        'shtime',
        'jptime',
        'feature',
        'material',
        'suggest',
        'description',
        'cataloggroup',
        'place',
        'scale',
        'slug',
        'user')



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = UserModel.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
```

> api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^productsTbls/$', views.ProductsTblListView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_list'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductsTblDetailView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_detail'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/pdelete/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$',views.api_delete_product,name='api_delete_p'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/register/$', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_register'),

]
```

> api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from ..models import *
from .serializers import ProductsTblSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .serializers import UserSerializer





class ProductsTblListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer



class ProductsTblDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer


class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):

    model = get_user_model()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny # Or anon users can't register
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer




@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def api_delete_product(request, id):
    # grab the image
    dp = ProductsTbl.objects.get(id=id)
    # security check
    if dp.user != request.user:
        raise Http404
    # delete the image
    dp.delete()
    # refresh the edit page
    return redirect('/api/productsTbls/')
```

> settings.py

```
........

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think from admin portal you need to provide permissions to user you have created for each method PUT,POST,GET

Comment: you mean in settings.py?

Comment: Yes, you have to provide permission in settings.py.

Comment: thank you ,I did it

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `settings.py` then it can work

> settings.py

```
......
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        #'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think from admin portal you need to provide permissions to user you have created for each method PUT,POST,GET or provide AllowAny permission(Which will give access to all your created user for any request). For more details refer [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)